# How do I make matrix row and column naming with C ++?

Tags: c++

I need to specify the row and column names of the matrix sent to me in C++.
Suppose that the matrix is a **3x3 matrix**. 
This is basic code for printing.

```
     int matris[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
     int  row[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
     char col[8] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'};

     for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
     {
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cout << matris[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
     }
```

But I want to print the matrix in this way and access its data.

```
  A B C
1 1 2 3
2 4 5 6
3 7 8 9
```

And i must write function like this

```
check("A","2");
```

**check("A","2")** function result must be 4. But i can't create a dynamic matrix. 
How can i write this code ? Help please , Thanks...

Comment: How many rows and columns there will be?

Comment: You might try to create mapping between row/column names and indexes.

Comment: @Yaseen Mollik If there is a 3x3 matrix, column names A B C,
row names will be 1 2 3... But if the matrix is 2x2, column names A, B
row names will be 1, 2.

Comment: @vahanco Can u explain on Code ?

Comment: @Code, I will try, but how do you know the size of the matrix? Is it hardcoded?

Comment: What will happen after 'Z'?

Comment: @vahanco Just i created basic matrix ,actually i have another project , this topic (this is part of the project).

Comment: @RoQuOTrix 29 letter enough.

Comment: @vahanco Did you wriite ? i can't :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you want that A translates to 0, B to 1 and so on.
Also you want that indexing starts 1-based not 0-based like in C++.

What you do now is simply translate the ASCII 'A' value to 0 and so on. Remember ASCII 'A' is 65.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h> 

int matris[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

int check(char c_col, char c_row) {
   int i_col = int(c_col) - 65; // 'A' is 65 translates to 0, etc.     
   int i_row = int(c_row) - 48 - 1; // '1' is ascii 49 translates to 0, etc.

   // check for wrong input
   // TODO: you should also cehck that you do not exceed matris size
   assert(i_col >= 0);
   assert(i_row >= 0);

   // return the value of "matris", matris has to be global accesible to work this way
   return matris[i_row][i_col];
}

int main() {
  std::cout << check('B', '2');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i understand :)

Answer (score -1):

Supposing you are hardcoding values like size of matrix and labels and matrix is global variable, your code should look like this:

```
int check(std::string column, std::string row) {
    int c = column[0] - 'A'; // Labels are single chars
    int r = row[0] - '1';
    if (c >= 0 && c <= 3 && r >= 0 && r <= 3)
         return matris[r][c];
    return 0; // or throw exception to handle invalid cooridinates passed to function
}
```

Using subtracting of ASCII codes should give you proper index in matrix.
However this approach is very bad because you hardcode size of matrix. Proper option should be passing size of row and columns to function as parameters. Also passing a matrix itself is better approach for me. Moreover, since you are using single character to label row/column, *check* function should have parameters defined as char, not *std::string*. Calling such function should look like this:

```
check('A', '2');
```

Comment: @kuchpoit At the time of matrix creation, I cannot integrate the parts representing the row and column names into my matrix. Actually my main problem here is how can I do this?

Comment: @kuchpoit I can create matrix by taking the row column from the user, it is not the problem, as I said, I cannot integrate the names of rows and columns when creating the matrix.

Comment: You don't have to integrate the names for your rows and colums. Imagine your symbols like translators, so an 'A' translates to a column 0 and a '2' translates to row '1'